# Variable's new value close to the old value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the new value of my variable close to the variable's old value.

```
bool FirstPos = true;
float LastPos = 0;
float LeftPos = -2.6f;

if(FirstPos)
{
   LeftPos = Random.Range(-2.6f, 1f);
   LastPos = LeftPos;
   FirstPos = false;
} else
{
   AddValue = Random.Range(0, 1.25f);
   NewValue = LastPos + AddValue;

   if((NewValue >= -2.6f) && (NewValue <= 1f)){
       LastPos = NewValue;
   } else {
       AddValue = Random.Range(0, 1.25f);
   } 
}
```

But I seriously have no idea how to make it work and make it as simple as it can be.

Scenario:

```
CurrentValue = Random.Range(-2.6f, 1f);
//CurrentValue returns -2.4 as value
```

`NewValue` returns number that's between `(-2.4 + 2)` or `(-2.4 - 2)`
but it can't go lower than `-2.6` or higher than `1`, because the new value needs to be between those 2 numbers but also close to the old number.

2 is in this case the highest number that gets added to the new value.

Comment: Could explain a bit more what it is exactly that you are trying to achieve , what the results currently are and what you expect them to be?

Comment: Well @Dave. The result is currently not how I want it (but that's obvious). Here's the situation: ``LastValue = -2.2;`` I would like to get a random number that's higher than -2.2 or lower, but the difference between the new value and old value shouldn't be higher than let's say 1.2f. Also, if the new value is below -2.6f, it should be -2.6f and not lower than that.

Comment: Mmm I'm still not sure what the full behaviour you are trying to achieve. I think some that you will find useful is something called rubber duck debugging. Google it and if it doesn't give you an answer to your question it will at least help you in asking your question better

Comment: I've added a scenario

Comment: What is purpose of the FirstPos bool?

Comment: If FirstPos is true, there's no LastValue, which means the whole process just began.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158771/discussion-between-dave-and-tripledeal).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
private static float GetNextRandomValue(Random random, 
                                        float current, 
                                        float absoluteOffset, 
                                        float floor = float.MinValue, 
                                        float ceiling = float.MaxValue)
{
    var next = (float)(current + absoluteOffset * (2 * random.NextDouble() - 1));
    return next > ceiling ? ceiling : (next < floor ? floor : next);
}
```

}

And, following your example in comments, you'd call it like:

```
var rnd = new Random();
GetNextRandomValue(rnd, -2.2f, 1.2f, -2.6f);
```

Comment: I'm only getting errors from your solution. Might it be the fact that my project is connected to a Unity project?